# MATLAB: How to divide items into groups using FOR Loops

Tags: matlab

I needed some help with a problem I'd been assigned in class. It's our introduction to `for loops`. Here is the problem:

Consider the following riddle.

*After a plane crash 3 people are stranded on a desert island. They spend
the first day gathering a pile of bananas. They decide to count them the
next morning and split them up between each equally.*

*In the middle of the night each person decides they can't trust their
fellow shipmates. So, each in turn, gets up and divides the pile into 3
equal sections and conceals their share. However, when dividing it there
was a single banana left over, which they gave to a nearby bear. When
morning comes, the group divides the remaining pile into 3 equal piles
and one banana is left over, which they give to a nearby bear.*

*What is the SMALLEST pile which solves the riddle?*

**Write a set of for-loops which can solve this riddle for ANY number
of people and ANY number of bears.**

I'm really unsure how to pursue this problem. I think it should involve two `for loops` (one within another?).

This is all I have so far:

```
function pile = IslandBananas(numpeople, numbears)
for pilesize=1:10000000
ultimatepile=(1/3)*((2/3)*(pile-1)-1) = 1;
end
for pile>1
ultimatepile=pile-1
end
```

I'm not really sure how correct this is, so I would really appreciate your input.

Comment: Why did you duplicate your question?! Not to mention the new code you provided does not have two nested for loops.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't have to be nested for-loops. And I didn't realize the edit option before. But frankly I still need help with this problem

Comment: If you tell me what exactly you don't understand about the solution I provided I will be glad to help you.

Comment: @voxeloctree provides a pretty good answer in your duplicate question without going too far and is willing to clarify any misunderstandings... I'd be pretty disappointed if someone answers this by doing your homework for you

Comment: I understand the logic behind the first for loop, where we take a third of every time the pile loses a banana before two-thirds are lost. But my specific questions are: 1) Do we need the "=1" in `...pile-1)-1) = 1`, and if so, what does that signify? And 2) Where and how do the `numpeople` and `numbears` variables come into play in this code?

Comment: Good questions. So when we we arrive at the final splitting, where (1/3)*((2/3)*(pile-1)-1), to make sure it is an absolute minimum we have to ensure that each person has *at least* one banana. So this will not factor in the code, but when we minimize `pile` (which is the variable we are trying to solve for), we want it so small so that everyone by the final splitting has only one banana. So when you iterate through pile, you won't always get rational numbers, e.g. try pile = 5 in the formula. So we need a condition to check for when smallestpile = 1.

Comment: As for the `numpeople` and `numbears` variables, think about how we developed the formula `smallestpile = (1/3)*((2/3)*(pile-1)-1)`. We subtracted 1 because there was 1 bear and we divided by 3 because there were 3 people. So what happens if there are 4 people and 1 bear? Then we can arrive at the formulation `(1/4)*((3/4)*(pile-1)-1)`. For 4 people and 2 bears we can arrive at `(1/4)*((3/4)*(pile-2)-2)`. So following the trend, what happens when we have `p` people and `b` bears?

Comment: My recommendation is this: really try to understand how the formula was developed, take the formula and manually plug in values for `pile`, desk check these values by working them out by hand, and understand what is going on when you iterate through the `pile` variable. Try values of say 5, 10, and 16. As a further hint, one of those numbers is a solution, but not the minimum solution. This is why we need the `if` statement, to find out when `smallestpile` is exactly 1.

Comment: Oh! I think I'm getting the gist of this problem now. I modified the first part of the code which I had before to reflect the two variables. `for pilesize=1:10000000
ultimatepile=(1/numpeople)*((1-(1/numpeople)*(pile-nummonkeys)-nummonkeys) = 1;
end`. Is that correct? And also, shouldn't it be `==1` instead of just `=1`?

Comment: And in regards to the if statement you mentioned, would we have to use an if or can we use a second for loop instead?

Comment: You are getting closer, but `ultimatepile=(1/numpeople)*((1-(1/numpeople)*(pile-nummonkeys)-nummonkeys)` has mistakes. Compare the equation again. Go through each step of my old solution and read it as `p` people and `b` bears instead of 3 people and three bears. Also the assignment you have `ultimatepile = formula = 1` is an improper assignment and will not work in matlab. The comparison operator `==` is correct, but only if you use it correctly! (Hint: `if` statement). Since we ran out of comment room, post an answer to your own question and we can work it out there.

Comment: You really don't need two `for` loops by the way. You technically don't even need one. You can do it with a `while` loop or by solving it directly with the equation. But my recommendation is a `for` loop and an `if` unless you are required to use two `for` loops. Either way you still need an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to MATLAB right now, but I think you simply need this:

```
p = input('Enter the number of people: ');
while(ceil(p) ~= floor(p))    %    `p` has to be an integer value.
    p = input('Nice try. Enter the number of people: ');
end
b = input('Enter the number of bears: ');
while(ceil(p) ~= floor(p))    &    `b` has to be an integer value.
    p = input('Nice try. Enter the number of bears: ');
end

for min_share = 1:Inf
    S = min_share*p + b;    %    `S` will hold the size of the pile.

    for ii = 1:p
        if(ceil(S) ~= floor(S))    %    The pile must have an integer size at the end of every itereation.
            break;
        end
        S = (S/2)*p + b;
    end

    if(ceil(S) == floor(S))    %    If the size of the current pile is an integer, we have found our answer.
        break;
    end
end
```

Comment: Shame. I already gave him the help and was letting him work through his homework...

Comment: @voxeloctree: Well, this is how I used to learn; go through others' code. That's why I put in all the comments. It's true that it would've been better had he done it himself though.

Comment: Stackexchange has even a [Q/A for learning style](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/3332/is-there-a-learning-style-that-involves-learning-best-by-teaching-others).

Comment: I appreciate both of your inputs. And while I do best by learning from examples (my professor doesn't give examples, which is why I have to learn from others), I also like to try things myself. Almost all education relies on observing other people and learning from their work. At this point in my MATLAB learning, I'm still in the "learning by examples" phrase. Only after I feel comfortable with that will I progress to trying entire problems by myself over and over. That being said, I still really do appreciate your input voxel, and I'm grateful for this website for providing me with resources.